# Pandas equivalent for R dplyr::first and dplyr::last when using groupby?

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe, dplyr, group

Is there a python pandas equivalent for dplyr::first and dplyr::last after grouping the dataframe?
In R, that is important because the dataframe, when grouped, has a "first" element for each "sub df" (different from just "head(1)" in python).

R example:

```
df <- tibble(
    value = seq(2, 10, 2),
    id = c("R", "R", "C", "R", "C")
)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(first_of_subdf = dplyr::first(value))
```

Result in R:

| value | id | first_of_subdf |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | R | 2 |
| 4 | R | 2 |
| 6 | C | 6 |
| 8 | R | 2 |
| 10 | C | 6 |

I do not know how to achieve a compact solution for python...

Answer (score 2):

Try with `transform`

```
df['first_of_subdf'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('first')
```

Note :

```
Pandas                  R 
agg                     summarise
transform               mutate
```